# natural sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to solve this exercise on sequences :
$$u_{n+1}=\frac{3u_n+4}{2u_n+3}$$ and $$u_0=1$$ for any natural number

1)Find a and b as $$u_{n+1}=a+\frac{b}{2u_n+3}$$

I've found a=3/2 and b=-1/2.

2) Show that $$0\leq u_n \leq 3/2$$ and $$u_{n+1}-\sqrt{2}=\frac{(u_n-\sqrt{2})(3-2\sqrt{2})}{2u_n+3}$$
Was not a problem.

3)Show that the real number $$c=\frac{3-2\sqrt{2}}{3} $$ satisfies $$0<c<1$$

4) However I do not succeed to solve the last two questions : I have to show that
$${\mid u_{n+1}-\sqrt{2}\mid}\leq c\mid u_n-{\sqrt{2}}\mid $$ and $${\mid u_{n}-\sqrt{2}\mid}\leq c^n\mid u_0-{\sqrt{2}}\mid $$ Do you have any ideas how to proove it ?
Thank you for your help ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that:
$${\mid u_{n+1}-\sqrt{2}\mid}\leq {\mid \frac{(u_n-\sqrt{2})(3-2\sqrt{2})}{2u_n+3}\mid}$$
Now 
$${\mid \frac{(u_n-\sqrt{2})(3-2\sqrt{2})}{2u_n+3}\mid}\leq c\mid u_n-{\sqrt{2}}\mid \Leftrightarrow\\
{\mid \frac{(3-2\sqrt{2})}{2u_n+3}\mid}\leq c  \Leftrightarrow\\
 3 \leq {\mid 2u_n+3\mid}$$

Why is the last inequality true?

The last claim follows now by induction on $n$.

Comment: Because $$0<u_n<3/2$$ so $$3<=|2u_n+3|$$ thank you very much for your quick answer ! Have a good day

Comment: @Matt: Greetings from your friendly community moderator. It seemed clear that your post was meant to be a response to this answer. In such a case you should post it as a *comment* here, so I moved it using my superpower. Read the FAQ. If you meant to do something else, @-ping me (the FAQ explains that, too). As a token of your appreciation you can either "upvote" this answer (click the grey uparrow to the left of this post, above a number), or you can "accept" it by clicking the grey checkmark. The latter signals to the community that you are happy with the answers you have gotten.

Comment: (cont') You can upvote many answers (some questions may receive more than 10), but accept only one. no pressure to do anything - your call. After you have gained a bit of reputation (FAQ) you can start upvoting elsewhere, too.